# VBA - Copy Paste Word Table without merging

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am currently doing some automatisation. Through this proccess, I am encoutering a problem. Using VBA I need to Copy some tables, and paste them at a specific place.

Thoses are my problems doing it :

1. How to Paste them after one an other ? Like I have two tables A and B and I want the pattern A B A' B' A'' B'' repeating
2. And doing so, how to make them not automatically merge ?

Here is the small sample that i'm trying to make work :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim n_copies As Integer

n_copies = 2

On Error GoTo close_file

Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.documents.Open("\copypaste.docx", ReadOnly = False)

For i = 1 To n_copies

WordDoc.bookmarks("copy").Range.Copy
WordDoc.bookmarks("paste").Range.Paste
Next i

WordDoc.SaveAs "testcpypaste.docx"
WordDoc.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub

close_file:
   WordDoc.Close savechanges:=False
   MsgBox Err.Description
   End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Are you copying from Word to Excel? Backwards? Please, post the code you have, where are you stuck and if any errors raise.

Comment: I am trying to copy from Word to Word, and i have uptaded the small sample that i'm trying to make word

Comment: Using VBA is no different to using the UI - you need to add a paragraph in between each table.

Comment: I tried inserting a paragraph at bookmark "paste" each time i loop, but it didn't help :/ i guess it's because the cursor is still inside the table

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA is no different to using the UI - you need to add a paragraph in between each table.

```
WordDoc.Bookmarks("copy").Range.Copy
Dim i As Integer
With WordDoc.Bookmarks("paste").Range
    For i = 1 To n_copies
        .InsertParagraph
        .paste
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .Move wdCharacter, -1
    Next i
End With
```